# How to add a new UV map to all selected objects?

Tags: python, scripting, uv

I would like to select multiple objects and add a custom UV set to all of them.
My version works for one selected object only but not for multiple selected objects.

```
import bpy

# Get all selected objects
selected_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects 

for obj in selected_objects:
    # Add new UV set
    bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_add() 
    # Set new UV set name for active UV set
    bpy.context.object.data.uv_layers.active.name = "UV_ao"
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You need to set the active object during the for loop. bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

Comment: Thank you a lot for the fast answer. All works fine!
I've added the right code below to help others.

Comment: Related: [How to add a UV Map to a Mesh Using Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/711/how-to-add-a-uv-map-to-a-mesh-using-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make the operator work for multiple objects, the current object in the loop needs to be assigned to [ViewLayer.active](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.LayerObjects.html#bpy.types.LayerObjects.active) before calling [uv_texture_add()](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html?highlight=uv_texture_add#bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_add):

```
import bpy

# Do the following for all selected objects
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects: 
    # Set current object in the selection as active
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj 
    # Add new UV set to active object
    bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_add() 
    # Set the name of the uv layer
    obj.data.uv_layers.active.name = "UV_ao"
```

Related: [Blender 2.8 API, python, set active object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/126581/31447)

---

Another way is [overriding the context](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add/6105#6105) of the operator by passing the object:

```
import bpy

# Do the following for all selected objects
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    # Override the context by passing the current object
    bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_add({'object': obj})
    # Set the name of the uv layer
    obj.data.uv_layers.active.name = "UV_ao"
```

Comment: Why are you assigning `"UV_ao"` string to the the active UV-layer of the object in context when looping through the objects anyway? Btw: you don't have to assign the object to the `ViewLayer.active`. You can override the context by passing the actual object `{'object': obj}` to `uv_texture_add()` operator, call is: `bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_add({'object': obj})`.

Comment: Sorry guys. I forgot to delete the last line, because of using it in my scene here. my objects have all a minimum of one UV set. But thank you a lot for the forther information, That helps!

Comment: No need to say sorry. Just read the comments again and try to understand them.

Answer (score 4):

You can get rid of the [uv_texture_add()](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html?highlight=uv_texture_add#bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_add) operator by adding a new [UVLoopLayer](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UVLoopLayers.html#bpy.types.UVLoopLayers.new):

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    # Make sure this is a mesh object and that it doesn't already use this UV Map
    if obj.type == 'MESH' and "UV_ao" not in obj.data.uv_layers:
        obj.data.uv_layers.new(name="UV_ao")
```

Comment: Thank you for this hint!

Comment: @brockmann Thanks for the edit, would you care to explain why the single quote around `'Mesh'`but not around the other string ?

Comment: Readability. "Use single quotes for enums, and double quotes for strings.", quote from: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_best_practice.html

Comment: @brockmann Oh, right. Thanks !